# How to deep find an array for a children property match in JS

Tags: javascript, recursion

Let's assume I have a similar object (a possible object for a website sidebar)

```
const sidebar = {
    label: "group 1-1",
    children: [
        {
            label: "group 1-2",
            children: [
                {
                    label: 'sub1-2-1',
                    slug: 'sub1-2-1'
                }, {
                    label: 'sub1-2-2',
                    slug: 'sub1-2-2'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            label: 'sub1-2',
            slug: 'sub1-2'
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I need to identify if any of the slug in the array include `sub1-2-2`.
I know I could make a recursion, but my test fails and keep falsify. Here's the code I've written so far:

```js
const sidebar = {
    label: "group 1-1",
    children: [
        {
            label: "group 1-2",
            children: [
                {
                    label: 'sub1-2-1',
                    slug: 'sub1-2-1'
                }, {
                    label: 'sub1-2-2',
                    slug: 'sub1-2-2'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            label: 'sub1-2',
            slug: 'sub1-2'
        }
    ]
}

function deepFind(group, location) {
    const parseSlug = (o) => o.slug === location
    return group.children ? deepFind(group.children, location) : group.some(parseSlug)
}


console.log(deepFind(sidebar,'sub-1-2-2'))
```

At first run, the children is a property, but the it becomes an array, so I am getting confused with the best way to make the recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a  small problem about your question that the sidebar may be an array,and I fixed it in my answer,

```js
const sidebar = {
  label: "group 1-1",
  children: [{
      label: "group 1-2",
      children: [{
        label: 'sub1-2-1',
        slug: 'sub1-2-1'
      }, {
        label: 'sub1-2-2',
        slug: 'sub1-2-2'
      }]
    },
    {
      label: 'sub1-2',
      slug: 'sub1-2'
    }
  ]
}

function deepFind(group, location, target = {}) {
  if (!Array.isArray(group)) group = [group]
  const parseSlug = (o) => o.slug === location
  const result = group.find(item => item.children ? deepFind(item.children, location, target) : parseSlug(item))
  if (!target.item) target.item = result
  return target.item
}
console.log(deepFind(sidebar, 'sub1-2-2'))

function deepSome(group, location) {
  if (!Array.isArray(group)) group = [group]
  const parseSlug = (o) => o.slug === location
  return group.some(item => item.children ? deepSome(item.children, location) : parseSlug(item))
}
console.log(deepSome(sidebar, 'sub1-2-2'))
```

Comment: Thanks @moon it works pretty well. I actually need a true or false as this is used in a `setState` so I removed the last if and added `return result ? true : false`

Comment: I think you need deepSome then deepFind,and I added it

Answer (score 1):

In your `return` statement you should apply the `some` method in the *other* case and not where you have it now. So:

```
return group.children ? group.children.some(child => deepFind(child, location))
                      : group.slug === location;
```

NB: note that you have an extra dash in your search string example, so it wont match.